# E: Re-installation of package `st-stlink-udev-rules` is required, but the required archive file cannot be found

Tags: upgrade, updates

I just started using Ubuntu and I got an error like this after downloading a program. I can't fix this error. I can't update or when I want to do any download I am getting this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Creating dependency tree... Done
Reading status info... Done
E: The package st-stlink-udev-rules needs to be reinstalled, but the required archive file cannot be found.
```

I think I also corrupted the `sources.list` file while trying to fix this. I need to install a few programs but I can't download anything including updates. Also I don't know how to download the `st-stlink-udev-rules` package. Since I am in the middle of a very important job, I need to fix this error without reinstalling the system.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. (1) This is an English speaking community. If you don't speak English, you can use an online translater. (2) Please don't add screenshots of textual output. Rather paste the text and format it as code.

Comment: Since you are new Ubuntu user, I would recommend a complete re-install. Please, backup any important documents and other files to a USB drive and re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: See [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Comment: Please run `grep -r "^deb " /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` and upload output to pastebin. The `st-stlink-udev-rules` packages was probably installed for STM32 microcontrollers. Do you plan to use them in near future?

Comment: Yes I encountered this error after downloading and deleting STM32Cube and I don't plan to use it anytime soon.

Output:
`/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with this command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq st-stlink-udev-rules
```